# An averages problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The average salary of the workers in a workshop is RS.8500. If the average monthly salary of 7 technicians is RS 10000 and the average monthly salary of the rest is RS 7800. Then the total number of the workers in the workshop is?

Answer (score 3):

What do we know?

1. We know that $\dfrac{\text{Total salary earned}}{\text{number of workers}} = 8500$.
2. And we know that $\dfrac{\text{salary earned by technicians}}{7 = \{\text{the number of tecnhicias} \}} = 10000$.
3. Finally, we know that $\dfrac{\text{salary earned by workers besides the technicians}}{\text{number of workers}-\text{number of technicians}} = 7800$.

From 2. we know the total salary earned by the technicians. We can use this to combine 1. and 3. into a system of equations with two unknowns: the total salary earned and the total number of workers.

Can you handle it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the number of workers among the "rest."  Then the total number of workers is $n+7$.

The overall average wage is is $8500$. So the **total** wage bill for all the workers is
$$(8500)(n+7).\tag{$1$}$$

We find the total wage bill in another way. The $n$ "other" workers between them earn $(7800)(n)$. The $7$ technicians between them earn $(10000)(7)$.  So the total wage bill is
$$(7800)(n)+(10000)(7).\tag{$2$}$$

The two expressions $(1)$ and $(2)$ for the total wage bill must give equal results. From this you should be able to get a nice linear equation, which is not difficult to solve for $n$.

**Remark:** There is a more informal way to solve the problem. It substitutes thinking for the algebra. The $7$ technicians each earn $1500$ more than the average salary of $8500$.  So between them, they get a total of $(1500)(7)$ more than they would if they got average salary.

This $(1500)(7)$ must come out of the hides of the poor "other workers," whose individual earnings are $700$ below average. So each of the poor other workers contributes $700$ to the wealth of the technicians. Since the total contribution is $(1500)(7)$, the number of "other workers" must be
$$\frac{(1500)(7)}{700}.$$
That is more or less how this type of problem was solved before "algebra" came into widespread use. People learned "rules" to partly automate the process, and bypass thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n$ represents the total number of workers. Total salary of $n$ workers=$8500n$.$$$$ Total Salary of $7$ technicians $=70000$ and total salary of the rest $n-7$ workers $=7800(n-7)$ $$\implies 70000+7800(n-7)=8500n$$ $$\implies 70000-7800*7=(8500-7800)n$$ $$\implies 15400=700n$$ $$\implies n=22$$ Thus, total number of workers $=22.$